# How to sign X509 token using WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, weblogic, wcf-security

I am working on a WCF client which must talk to an Oracle WebLogic service. The service enforces mutual certificate authentication.

We are not, however, able to satisfy the policy and the server logs an error stating:

> "WSM-00081: The X.509 certificate is not signed."

I have been wondering what the exact meaning of this is. The Oracle documentation states:

> WSM-00081: The X.509 certificate is not signed.
>
> Cause: The X509 token used was not signed according to requirements of certificate authentication scenario.
>
> Action: Sign the X509 token (depending upon the reference mechanism used) for certificate authentication.
>
> Level: 1
>
> Type: ERROR
>
> Impact: Security

(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/core.1111/e10113/chapter_wsm_messages.htm)

After some research, we found out that we can disable the check in the service policy configuration file by setting `is-signed="false`:

```
<orasp:x509-token orasp:enc-key-ref-mech="direct" orasp:is-encrypted="false"
              orasp:is-signed="false"
              orasp:rcpt-enc-key-ref-mech="direct"
              orasp:rcpt-sign-key-ref-mech="direct"
              orasp:sign-key-ref-mech="direct"/>
```

My two theories:

- The certificate needs to be signed by a CA

  - We checked using an a certificate signed by a CA, but this made no difference
  - However, we might have made som errors when configurating this. Should we try it over?
- We somehow need to sign the included BinarySecurityToken's, which are included in the request.

  - However, I have no idea how I can do this

Have I completely misunderstood the subject or can any of you give some pointers to what the problem might be and how it can be solved?

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate are a certificate from a trusted provider?

Comment: Is it a 2 way authentication? Also have you checked if the provider exists as a trusted authority in the oracle weblogic service? Make sure that if its a 2 way authentication then both certificates are signed by a trusted authority

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the security token as part of the request.

In the binding element of your config set the security element mode to [SecurityMode.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.securitymode.aspx) and the message element clientCredentialType to [MessageCredentialType.Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecredentialtype.aspx):

```
<security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"
        algorithmSuite="Default"
        establishSecurityContext="true" />
</security>
```

Next, create an endpoint behavior to resolve the location of your [client certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391.aspx):

```
<behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior">
    <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="Contoso.com" 
            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
            storeName="TrustedPeople"
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
    </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```